# Is it possible to modify xml with the jquery xml parser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I have an xml file which contains an attribute called "transform".

Example :

```
<xml>
<g transform="translate(50,20)">
 <g class="x axis" transform="translate(0,150)">
 </g>
</g>
```

I need the text in the transform attribute from **translate(50,20)** to a string variable

I can't find an example with the jquery xml parser that I can get to work so I'm not sure if its possible?

My code at the minute is as follows :

```
 xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString ),
     $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
     $title = $xml.find( 'g[transform]' ).each(function(i,j)
                {           
                    $(j).each(function(i,j){
                        var id = $(this).attr("transform");
                                console.log(id)
                        });

        });
```

This successfully finds the element and prints it but I'm not sure how to modify it

Comment: Doesn't look like valid XML, are you sure the parser doesn't throw an error ?

Comment: The xml is fine..I just took the line of interest for an example. I change it to the xml in the answer provided by @Alex to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

As @adeneo also suggested in his comment, you have to pass-in valid XML:

```
<xml>
  <g transform="translate(50,20)">
    <g class="x axis" transform="translate(0,150)">
      Excluded
    </g>
  </g>
</xml>
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/BAatq/.